# Sampling an image's pixels?

Tags: javascript, html, pixel

I have an `<img>` loading from a URL and I want to see what colors the pixels have.

```js
var img = document.getElementById('image');
img.src = "https://someimage.url/image.jpg";
img.onload = function () {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
};
```

At this point, due to `.getImageData`, the console says `operation is insecure`.

I try to fix this by adding `img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";`.

This gets rid of the error message, but leaves me with an empty, unloaded image.

Other posts have suggested moving components out of `img.onload`, but it's the same result.

Some have suggested that this path is not possible due to security reasons. If so, what is another way of approaching this? How else does one determine the color of a certain pixel displayed on screen?

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas#getting_the_pixel_data_for_a_context) for `getImageData` seems to show exactly what I want to do. It looks like the only difference is that their image is on their own server instead of someone else's. Is this the only way around this problem? And if that's the case, would a more straightforward concept be:

1. download image to your own server
2. process it locally
3. delete image after processing

This might be more straightforward, but probably won't scale very well?

Comment: You had answered to your own question quite well, yes CORS does apply.

Comment: That is the expected behavior.  When an image from another domain is drawn on a canvas the browser marks the canvas as "tainted" and restricted.  See: [Allowing cross-origin use of images and canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image)